# Configuring mod_wsgi for wamp server on windows

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am new in Django development. I have created an Django application and tested in development server i.e. 127.0.0.1:8080/mysite. Then I decided to run this app on Apache server 2.4.9. 
As all we know the best option is configuring mod_wsgi.
My problem is Apache server never runs after configuring as bellow:

1. Keep mod_wsgi.so 
   [downloaded](https://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so) on 'C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\modules\'.
2. Insert "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so" to httpd.conf
3. Restart wamp server

I am using 32 bit of Python,Apache and mod_wsgi. Python is installed for all user. Please help me -

Answer (score 0):

First of all copy mod_wgi in modules folder, 
then add following to httpd.conf modules list:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

attention that naming is important (should suffix with _module)

Add the following to your httpd.conf

```
Include path_to_your_proj/django_wsgi.conf
```

django_wsgi.conf file:

```
 WSGIScriptAlias path_to/django.wsgi

<Directory project_path>
   Allow from all
   Order allow,deny
</Directory>

Alias /static path_to_static_files
```

django.wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

#Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\','/')
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, os.pardir))
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'proj_dir_name')

if PROJECT_ROOT not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)
if SETTINGS_DIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(SETTINGS_DIR)

os.chdir(SETTINGS_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'proj_name.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**If you're using a virtualenv (that I suggest) do as follows:**

httpd.conf file:

```
# virtual env02
<VirtualHost ip-adddress_or_dns:port_if_other_than_80>
    ServerName just_a_name     # like : app01
    ServerAlias just_an_alias #  like : app01.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/env02.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/env02.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  direct_path_to_you_wsgi_with_forward_slashes # like:  C:/virtual/venv01/proj_name/wsgi.py
    <Directory proj_dir_with_forward_slashed>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static path_to_static_folder_with_forward_slashes
    <Directory path_to_static_folder_with_forward_slashes>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
# end virtual env02
```

wsgi.py file:

```
activate_this = 'c:/virtual/env02/scripts/activate_this.py'
# execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys
import site
# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('c:/Organizer/virtual/env02/Lib/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('c:/virtual/proj_name')
sys.path.append('c:/virtual/proj_name/default_app_name')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'default_app_name.settings'

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "default_app_name.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Thanx for your effort. Is it necessary to integrate with django project? I just want to install mod_wsgi and run Apache server correctly which is not being succeeded! S

Comment: Try different versions of mod_wsgi, use just apache alone server not wamp or xamp

Comment: This time I am having following error, while trying to load mod_wsgi in apache alone server:     httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 72 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load 
modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: I get the same error. According to the site, you now have to compile from source for the so file or get the appropriate version. so apache2.2.x not apache2.4.x and so on. You have to get very specific versions to get it to work properly with the mod_wsgi.so file. Im about to opt for WSFL since that just is already much easier.

Comment: Could you take a look at this question too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701228/how-to-resolve-wsgi-module-not-found-error-on-windows)