# How to resolve wsgi_module not found error on windows?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

**Summary:**

After installing the **mod_wsgi** with `pip` correctly, and inserted its config related stuff to the **http.conf (apache)**. The wsgi_module was loaded successfully as shown in the log below:

> **[Mon Dec 10 10:39:39.048697 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 16708:tid 692]** mod_wsgi (pid=16708): Python home c:/users/.../appdata/local/programs/python/python37.
>
> **[Mon Dec 10 10:39:39.048697 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 16708:tid 692]** mod_wsgi (pid=16708): Initializing Python.
>
> **[Mon Dec 10 10:39:39.081683 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 16708:tid 692]** mod_wsgi (pid=16708): Attach interpreter ''.
>
> **[Mon Dec 10 10:39:39.084682 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 16708:tid 692]** mod_wsgi (pid=16708): Adding 'E:/projects/python/...' to path.
>
> **[Mon Dec 10 10:39:39.089662 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 16708:tid 692]** mod_wsgi (pid=16708): Imported 'mod_wsgi'.

**Question:**

But at the apache modules, the wsgi_module says *No module file* as shown in the picture below:

[image]

**More detail:**

And when I click on the *wsgi_module*, this output is displayed:

> There is 'LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so' line in
>   httpd.conf file but there no 'mod_wsgi.so' file in
>   apachex.y.z/modules/ directory.

It is my http.conf lines which are associated with the mod_wsgi:

```
LoadFile "c:/users/.../appdata/local/programs/python/python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/.../appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/.../appdata/local/programs/python/python37"
WSGIPythonPath "E:/projects/python/..."
WSGIScriptAlias /scripts "E:/projects/python/.../.../wsgi.py"

DocumentRoot "E:\\projects\\python\\...\\...\\..."
<Directory "E:\\projects\\python\\...\\...\\...">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Allow From all
    </Files>
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews +ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride all
    Allow From all

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Comment: You have `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` somewhere in the httpd.conf.

Comment: NO, I don't have any like that, just my line: `LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/.../appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"`