# Is there a way to test and deploy Python Flask app with XAMPP Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, wamp, mod-wsgi

For a project at my university my task was to make a web-application for a professor. The application is a Python Flask app which generates a matplotlib plot depending on user input. My application is done and bug free, but the professor asked if I could test it with WAMP (I have XAMPP installed and I guess it's the same thing). I've read about and tried mod_wsgi but to no avail. My questions are how to install and use mod_wsgi in this specific situation, or are there any other ways for the app to work. Additionally, when I send the app to my professor, I presume he will most likely have to install all python packages used for building the app as well. Is there any way around this problem, so that the professor only has to put my app on his server without installing all python and other packages? It's my first post so I apologize for any mistakes. Also I didn't put any code since I thought it wouldn't be relevant, but if someone corrects me I'll put it up.

Comment: You'll definitly need all the python packages to be installed on the python instance that the WAMP server will use. You might wanto to create a batch script to deploy your app, which will include a `python.exe -m pip install requirements.txt` line in order to install everything you need. As for WAMP itself (or XAMPP), why go the apache PHP way when this is definitly not designed for ? Why not go the gunicorn way ?

Comment: @OrsirisdeJong As far as I know, he (my professor) has multiple of these apps (one for every subject in his class, all of them connected through a menu), all of which are PHP based with a JS plotting library. I learned this only after 90% of my app was done. The initial agreement between him and I was that I will be working in python, and I didn't ask further questions since he is a professor at a computing engineering college after all, and I didn't know much about deploying different backend apps at the time.

Comment: Fair enough, so if you're stuck with WAMP, there are a lot of existing topics about the subject on stackoverflow, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458460/configuring-mod-wsgi-for-wamp-server-on-windows Good luck. I'd still go the gunicorn route, and use WAMP as reverse proxy for gunicorn so you can use a full blown Python stack and still be WAMP compatible.